# CSS boxes not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a web application and my Css panels keep jumping all over the place. The panels have an image with a 4:3 aspect ratio and a description section. It works well sometimes and jumps off sometimes when I add new products to the catalogue. I can't set a fixed height because I need it to be responsive, and Im too lazy to write media queries for each viewport.
[image]
I am working with Bootstrap 4. Any gurus out there who have any insights? My site is hosted at lunchmagic.co.ke. You can inspect the page to see my code.
Thank you

Comment: that means you need to show the code to us

Comment: Can you share a fiddle to this ?

Comment: we will NEVER inspect a site. share your RELEVANT code here

Comment: bound your every row with class "row"

Answer (score 2):

Apply `min-height` to each box, after that, your boxes will display properly.

Comment: that's a pretty ugly workaround. there are better and cleaner ways to to this

Comment: This approach worked nicely for my desktop. However, mobile viewports had too much space. So i wrote media queries and it is just elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Make fix height or min-height for all of them that fix your issue

```
.box {
  height:xxx; /*your height*/
}
```

Comment: actually min-height is much better since it allows the container to grow